# Ruby pick up a value in hash of array to reformat into a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Is there a way I can pick a `value` in `hash` of `array`, and reformat it to be only hash?

Is there any method I can do with it?

**Example**

```
[
  {
    "qset_id" => 1,
    "name" => "New1"
    },
  {
    "qset_id" => 2,
    "name" => "New2"
  }
]
```

**Result**

```
{
  1 => {
      "name" => "New1"
  },
  2 => {
        "name" => "New2"
    }
}
```

Comment: When you give an example (generally a good thing) it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [...]`). That way, readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Moreover, all readers will refer to the same variables, which is also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the first hash and map it into a second hash:

```
h1.map{|h| {h['qset_id'] => {'name' => h['name']}} }
# => [{1=>{"name"=>"New1"}}, {2=>{"name"=>"New2"}}]
```

... but that would return an array. You could pull the elements into a second hash like this:

```
h2 = {}
h1.each do |h| 
  h2[h['qset_id']] = {'name' => h['name']}
end
>> h2
=> {1=>{"name"=>"New1"}, 2=>{"name"=>"New2"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can basically do arbitary manipulation using `reduce` function on array or hashes, for example this will get your result

```
array.reduce({}) do |result, item|
  result[item["qset_id"]] = { "name" => item["name"] }
  result
end
```

You can do the same thing with `each.with_object` do:

```
   array.each.with_object({}) do |item, result|
     result[item["qset_id"]] = { "name" => item["name"] }
   end
```

it's basically the same thing but you don't have to make each iteration return the result (called a 'memo object').

Comment: Fore me the output of this doesn't match the requirement: `[nil, {"name"=>"New1"}, {"name"=>"New2"}]`

Comment: I like that `with_object` better than mine.